# The rust file is not working as I `cargo run` with crontab

Tags: linux, cron, crontab, rust

I type `sudo -i` to proceed to edit commands of crontab.

I've written the following line inside the file of crontab.

`@reboot cd /home/username/superuser &&  cargo run;`

The following content is inside the `main.rs` of the normal cargo.

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let data = "rust language";
    fs::write("/home/username/foo", data).expect("Unable to write file");
}
```

As I reboot my computer , actually the file `foo` was not generated in a directory.

What is(/are) cause(s)?

Answer (score 0):

As only the objective is to execute a program file, then one can run the that file with crontab with `@reboot /home/username/path/to/cargo/package/target/filename`